# Projecting a rectangular image onto a curved background

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, graphics, geometry, projection

Given a rectangular company logo, I want to project it on a curved background similar to the ones in this picture. I'm looking for a programmatic solution rather than a manual one, because I need to apply the transformation to a lot of pictures.

[image: curved podium background]

I've tried the OpenCV projection methods using Python, without any results so far

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Post an example result so we can see how much of the curved surface is covered by the image. Does the image get wrapped to the cylinder also as a separate wrapping?

Comment: The question needs more elaboration, but as far as I could get from your question, I can say, it's a good idea to use a chessboard image to calibrate the projection, then apply that transformation to the images.

Comment: Thanks for replying, and sorry for not answering sooner. I can not share the sample due to proprietary reasons. 

The best way to describe what I'm trying to do (hope it's clearer) is to make it seem as if someone printed out the logo on a sheet of paper and then pasted it on a curved background (like the podium I originally posted)